# Need to get values from XML

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I would need to get the values from the XML nodes say from the sample below XML.

```html
<Names>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <LastName>White</LastName>
    </Name>
</Names>
```

The code which im using for doing that is below.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...    </Names>"
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

This is working fine in a separate solution. but it's not retreiving the values when i use the same code as a part in one of my application.
Basically my application makes a call to a WCF web servcie and that web service in retun sends the string. I'm converting that string to XML document and when I'm wirting that document in sever as a XML file, i'm able to see the entire XML. But when I try to traverse and get the nodes for the same, it's unsuccessful.
I'm not getting any error but the control is not going into the **foreach()** loop. Which means **xnList.Count** is 0 (zero).

I have been trying to figure out this for past 3 days. 
Could anyone please help me out in clearing this issue.

Thanks in Advance Guys!!!

Comment: `XmlDocument` is an old-style way to work with XML in C#. Use `XDocument` when it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Place a breakpoint at line 3, what is the value of `xml.OuterXml`? If it is empty, then you acquire your string incorrectly. If it is not, then try to add `xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name")` to Watches. If it is not empty, then it works. If it is empty, then try another XPath like `*` and look through XML again - something's definitely wrong.

Comment: You must have a namespace in the XML declaration. That's most likely the cause of the issue. If you do, then you need to add the namespace to your xpath query and use the xml namespace manager.

Comment: my guess is your xml return from server is different from your sample xml, might contains extra information like namespace

Comment: Since your code snippet and xml works on my machine, I'm going to conquer with the others that there is something wrong with the xml syntax of your input.  If you're still stuck, I can post what I have in an answer if you wish to use it as a reference.

Comment: you guys should actually read the problem/docs before commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is c#.  try this

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString);
XmlNodeList names = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Names");
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++){
  string firstName = names.Item["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName = names.Item["LastName"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

Comment: I didn't see the comments... I'd try those first

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. This worked. :)
Others.... Thanks a lot for your valuable comments and time :) :)'

Comment: lol those were the first lines of c# I've ever written.  I guess it really is exactly the same as java with some case changes